# I can't get the overflowY option to work in magnific popup

Tags: magnific-popup

I can't get the overflowY option to work in the magnific popup jquery add-on

I notice that the demo on the actual site does not work either.

Site: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

Link: The one that says "Load content via ajax"

Is this a known bug with magnific?  When I try it it just ignores it.  I have resorted to other measures to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Solved it by using this option instead:

```
image: {
    verticalFit: false
}
```

I found it on this page http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/ -> it's the second image of the very first example "single image lightbox".